# Publishing Maven artifact to artifactory with different artifact ID

Tags: gradle, artifactory

New to Maven Publishing. Our team has started using Artifactory and I'm trying to figure out how to publish to it, but using a custom artifact ID. Here's the relevant part of my build.gradle file

```
def applicationName = 'example-api'
def applicationVersion = '1.0.0.1'
def group = 'com.example.api'
def archiveName = "${applicationName}##${applicationVersion}"

bootWar {
  archiveFileName = "${archiveName}.war"
}

publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      artifact(file("build/libs/${archiveName}.war"))
      afterEvaluate {
        artifactId archiveName
        groupId group
        version applicationVersion
      }
    }
  }
}

artifactory {
  contextUrl = "http://172.17.0.2:32447/artifactory"
  publish {
    repository {
      repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
      username = 'admin'
      password = 'password1'
      maven = true
    }

    defaults {
      publications('mavenJava')
      publishBuildInfo = true
      publishArtifacts = true
      publishPom = false
    }

  }

  clientConfig.info.setBuildName(applicationName)
  clientConfig.info.setBuildNumber(applicationVersion)
}
```

But it seems it's never keeps the same name as the WAR file that's produced in the build. This is the closest I've gotten:

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to have the artifact be called just 'example-api##1.0.0.1.war' since it will be deployed to Tomcat.

When I try to remove groupId, Artfactory seems unable to create a repo URL, and if I omit the the version, the artifact name is then `example-api##1.0.0.1-unspecified.war`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is the expected behaviour.

Maven artifact names are strictly `<artifactId>-<version>.<extension>`.
So when you set the publication configuration as follows:

- `artifactId` = `example-api##1.0.0.1`
- `version` = `1.0.0.1`
- `extension` = `war`

It results in an artifact named `example-api##1.0.0.1-1.0.0.1.war`

I would strongly recommend dropping the version from the `artifactId` part, to be better aligned with Maven conventions.

An alternative would be to use [an Ivy repository](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:ivy_repositories), which has more flexibility around specifying the artifact name.